# MacBook Pro Dual LCD

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, displayport

Would it be possible to customize a macbook so that it has 2 screens instead of 1?

what i mean is, could i hook up the lcd from another macbook and connect so that it has 2 screens..

if it could work, would i have to connect it via minidisplayport or is there a way to connect it to the video board..

essentially something like this..

http://www.freeonsmash.com/news/2008/12/12/apple-macbook-tribook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this, maybe cover your needs:

```
http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html
```

but it is commercial 30$.

(You sure know this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924)

Comment: how is screenrecycler different from http://synergy-foss.org/  ?

Comment: Yeah but it's not the same is it? Synergy is pretty much an automatic keyboard-mouse switch whereas ScreenRecycler is using the second computer's display as a display for your first computer.

Comment: @XQYZ - youre right. The synergy is only a sort of kvm. So, you can share your mouse and keyboard between more systems, but does not externd the current system with a second display.

Comment: @XQYZ you are right. Guess I was a bit too jumpy